# php скрипт выполняется автоматически при входе на сайт

Tags: php, post

программа должна считывать данные в формах и отправлять, при нажатии кнопки, но в итоге ещё выполняется при входе на сайт или обновлении страницы, подскажите в чём проблема.

```
<?php
$numberPhone = $_POST['phone'];

$name = $_POST['name'];

if(!empty($_POST)){ $ch = curl_init("https://sms.ru/sms/send");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(

    "api_id" => "*********",

    "multi" => array( 
        "8-000-000-00-00"=> ('Имя: '. $name . ', телефон: ' . $numberPhone),
        $numberPhone => ("Мы с вами свяжемся.")),
 
    "json" => 1
     
     )));

     $body = curl_exec($ch);

     curl_close($ch);

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: что такое "выполняется автоматически"?

Comment: при входе на сайт или обновлении страницы

Comment: Что значит "при входе на сайт"?

Comment: Переменную какую-нибудь сделайте : `$_SESSION['tasksendsms']` И её и проверяйте : `if(isset($_SESSION['tasksendsms']))`